# How can I get the Steam ID of a game from its name using the Steam API?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I've been looking through the Steam API documentation, and there are a number of services that provide information on a game in the Steam web store, however they all seem to require the Steam ID of the game as a parameter. This can be done with user IDs, where the API will provide the User ID if given a username, but I can't find how to do the same feature with the game library. Is there anyway to provide the name of a game and get its Steam ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/

You can traverse the JSON object and look for your ID using the game name.

Comment: Just to clarify for those (like me, 10 minutes ago) who were having trouble figuring out how to access this.

Steam has a main API section called the "Steam Web API". The Steam Web API collection includes: ISteamNews, ISteamUserStats, and ISteamUser: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

The ISteamApps API is _NOT_ part of the Steam Web API!

There is separately, a "Steam**works** Web API" -- this includes the ISteamApps API which is linked above: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api